# Ideas of display data like most social network apps

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I want to display data like most social network apps use now. They use a lot of separated frames. In each frame it has texts, pictures, buttons and something else. I absolutely don't know how to do this. I think I can use table view and use grouped style (remove group name label) to display it but I don't know whether I can put button on it and whether it is the smartest way to fix my problem.

Can you explain clearly for me or just give me tutorial, links or something related to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An experience shared by a Facebook developer on how they built the iOS app.

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-rebuilding-facebook-for-ios/10151036091753920

Comment: Thank u. I read it and they wrote "If you have a lot of stories in your news feed, UITableView throws a small spanner..." and "At the moment, stories in news feed consist of headers with profile pictures and timestamps, messages, photos, videos, the "Like" and "Comment" buttons, and a whole lot more" so I think they use table view to display data (sorry english is my 2rd language). But actually i dont know how to do this, can u give me more information. Thank u in advance.

Comment: Yes they do use UITableView control to display news feed, timeline, etc. I would suggest you read the apple's tableview programming guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Comment: Ok i will read it. Is it ok if i post questions (something i dont understand while i read tutorial) here because i dont see your email on your stackoverflow account :D ?

Comment: Go through a few sample apps from apple. Implement your own version. Search through SO for questions that you are looking for, if you don't find it. Create one.

Comment: You might wanna up-vote or accept the ans if you have found it to be helpful.

Comment: I accepted your ans. But I cant vote for your ans because it told me Vote Up requires 15 reputation :D.